# Connecting to an SSL-Only Cloud SQL database through Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-shell

So obviously I have my certificates for connecting to the database externally, but how do I connect to an SSL-only database using Cloud Shell?

If I tap "Connect using Cloud Shell" on the Cloud SQL page and use their pre-filled Shell command:

`gcloud sql connect INSTANCENAME --user=root --quiet`

It won't let me log in using my root password, and as far as I can see there are no options to supply certificates like there is when just using a cli mysql client. If I turn forced SSL off, I can connect correctly. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: As stated on the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell) gcloud command group doesn't support SSL connections to your CloudSQL instance. You can try instead something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl)

Comment: @TasosV ahh so I'm not missing something obvious, it legitimately doesn't support it, thought as much, if you leave this as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as answered, cheers mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell) for CloudSQL

> gcloud command group doesn't support SSL connections to your CloudSQL
> instance.

So, it's an expected behaviour that doesn't allow you to log in.

You can try instead something like [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the digitalization of the answer above:
SSL is not supported and we don't need turn forced SSL off. Instead, we need to use [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#cloud-shell). It is quite easy to install.